# Search within Bootstrap Tabs

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap 3 pill tabs and would like to offer a functionality similar to filtering a table with live.

In other words, as the user types - make irrelevant tabs disappear, so the user can tell that they do not contain the typed string.

I'm not sure how to go about this, any general ideas would be appreciated. Code snippets as well, obviously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little bit different approach (checks content of tabs, not the titles).

```
var tabLinks = $('.nav > li'),
  tabsContent = $('.tab-content > div'),
  tabContent = [],
  string,
  i,
  j;

for (i = 0; i < tabsContent.length; i++) {
  tabContent[i] = tabsContent.eq(i).text().toLowerCase();
}
$('input').on('input', function() {
  string = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
  for (j = 0; j < tabsContent.length; j++) {
    if (tabContent[j].indexOf(string) > -1) {
      tabLinks.eq(j).show();
      tabLinks.eq(j).find('a').tab('show');
    } else {
      tabLinks.eq(j).hide();
    }
  }
});
```

### **[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/makshh/pen/QyXRMd)**

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#search').on('input', function() {
  var search = this.value;
  $('.nav.nav-pills li').hide().filter(function() {
    //get target from tabs anchor and create jQuery Object
    var $target = $($(this).find('a').attr('href'));
    //Return true if the text contains the search word
    return ($target.text().indexOf(search) != -1);
  }).show().eq(0).find('a').click();
  //get 1st item (index of 0) and click the anchor to set it to active and activate
  //the associated tab-pane
})
```

You could try something like this. 
https://jsfiddle.net/SeanWessell/dsnwkw66/